# Necesitaria ayuda con la lógica del siguiente ejercicio JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse

El ejercicio simula la extracción de dinero de un cajero automático. Lo que no puedo lograr es iniciar el cajero con 3000 euros y que cuando yo doy click en el JButton, que vaya disminuyendo valor inicial del cajero (Osea que el cajero me permita retirar x veces, siempre y cuando el mismo tenga dinero).

CÓDIGO:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ventana1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel ventana1;
    private JLabel l1;
    private JComboBox comboPesos;
    private JComboBox comboCuenta;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Ventana1 frame = new Ventana1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ventana1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        ventana1 = new JPanel();
        ventana1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(ventana1);
        ventana1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDineroAExtraer = new JLabel("Dinero a extraer");
        lblDineroAExtraer.setBounds(20, 39, 126, 14);
        ventana1.add(lblDineroAExtraer);

        comboPesos = new JComboBox();
        comboPesos.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"0", "50", "100", "150", "200", "250", "300", "350", "400", "450", "500"}));
        comboPesos.setBounds(20, 64, 100, 20);
        ventana1.add(comboPesos);

        JLabel lblTipoDeCuenta = new JLabel("Tipo de cuenta");
        lblTipoDeCuenta.setBounds(204, 39, 126, 14);
        ventana1.add(lblTipoDeCuenta);

        comboCuenta = new JComboBox();
        comboCuenta.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Caja de ahorro", "Cuenta corriente", ""}));
        comboCuenta.setBounds(204, 64, 135, 20);
        ventana1.add(comboCuenta);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Extraer");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int pesos=Integer.parseInt((String)comboPesos.getSelectedItem());
                String cuenta=(String)comboCuenta.getSelectedItem();
                int inicial=3000;
                if (pesos<=200 && cuenta=="Caja de ahorro" || pesos<=400 && cuenta=="Cuenta corriente") {
                    l1.setText("Correcto");
                    inicial=inicial-pesos;
                    if (pesos>inicial) {
                        l1.setText("Fuera de servicio");
                    }
                } else {
                    l1.setText("Incorrecto");
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(20, 152, 89, 23);
        ventana1.add(btnNewButton);

        l1 = new JLabel("resultado");
        l1.setBounds(129, 156, 100, 14);
        ventana1.add(l1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que realices el recorrido para ayudarte a usar correctamente este sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ! la revisare detenidamente

Comment: Si bien tu pregunta abunda en detalles, lo cual es bueno, también da demasiada información y no se logra comprender cuál es el problema puntual y específico que tienes. Por favor lee [ask] y [mcve], que te ayudarán a plantear de mejor manera tu problema. Un saludo y bienvenido.

Comment: Soy nuevo en dicha plataforma ! Lo tendré en cuenta  a partir de ahora. Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo mi código fuente espero que te sirva.

Recuerda Java es totalmente orientado a objetos, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es pensar en como introducirías un objeto de la vida real a código!!

Este es mi [código fuente](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTZjgX0o15O48hAE8TFnibbzl1qE8IWK/view?usp=sharing) espero te sirva

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CajeroAutomatico {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CreameCajero cajero = new CreameCajero();

    }

}

class CreameCajero extends JFrame{


    public CreameCajero() {

        setTitle("Cajero Automatico: By Jeysson Ureña");

        setBounds(350,100,600,400);

        setVisible(true);

        add(new LaminaCajero());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class LaminaCajero extends JPanel{

    private JLabel labelBalance, espacio, espacio2, espacio3, labelTexto, labelDinero, labelCuenta;

    private JComboBox comboDinero, comboCuenta;

    private JPanel laminaLabel, laminaCajero, laminaBoton;

    private boolean montoPermitido;

    private Box cajaTexto, cajaCajero, cajaBoton;

    private JButton botonExtraer;

    private int balance;


    public LaminaCajero() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        laminaLabel = new JPanel();

        laminaLabel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        balance = 3000;

        labelBalance = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance + " euros");

        labelBalance.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));

        cajaTexto = Box.createVerticalBox();

        cajaTexto.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "1. TEXTO CONSULTA"));

        cajaTexto.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        labelTexto = new JLabel("Esperando consulta");

        labelTexto.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));

        laminaLabel.add(labelBalance);

        espacio = new JLabel(" ");

        espacio2 = new JLabel(" ");

        espacio3 = new JLabel(" ");

        laminaLabel.add(labelTexto);

        laminaLabel.add(espacio);

        laminaLabel.add(espacio2);

        laminaLabel.add(espacio3);

        cajaTexto.add(laminaLabel);

        add(cajaTexto, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //...............................................//

        laminaCajero = new JPanel();

        laminaCajero.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        cajaCajero = Box.createVerticalBox();

        cajaCajero.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "2. CAJERO"));

        cajaCajero.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        labelDinero = new JLabel("Dinero a extraer: ");

        labelDinero.setForeground(Color.white);

        labelDinero.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 25));

        comboDinero = new JComboBox();

        comboDinero.addItem(0);

        comboDinero.addItem(50);

        comboDinero.addItem(100);

        comboDinero.addItem(150);

        comboDinero.addItem(200);

        comboDinero.addItem(250);

        comboDinero.addItem(300);

        comboDinero.addItem(350);

        comboDinero.addItem(400);

        comboDinero.addItem(450);

        comboDinero.addItem(500);

        labelCuenta = new JLabel("Tipo de cuenta");

        labelCuenta.setForeground(Color.white);

        labelCuenta.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 25));

        comboCuenta = new JComboBox();

        comboCuenta.addItem("Ahorro");

        comboCuenta.addItem("Corriente");

        laminaCajero.add(labelDinero);

        laminaCajero.add(comboDinero);

        laminaCajero.add(labelCuenta);

        laminaCajero.add(comboCuenta);

        cajaCajero.add(laminaCajero);

        add(cajaCajero, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //................................................//

        laminaBoton = new JPanel();

        laminaBoton.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        cajaBoton = Box.createVerticalBox();

        cajaBoton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "3. BOTON"));

        cajaBoton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        botonExtraer = new JButton("Extraer");

        botonExtraer.addActionListener(new EventoCajero());

        laminaBoton.add(botonExtraer);

        cajaBoton.add(laminaBoton);


        add(cajaBoton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private class EventoCajero implements ActionListener{

        private Object boton, cuenta;

        private int dinero = 0;


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            montoPermitido = false;

            boton = e.getSource();

            dinero = (int) comboDinero.getSelectedItem();

            cuenta = comboCuenta.getSelectedItem();

            if(boton == botonExtraer) {

                if(cuenta.equals("Ahorro")) {

                    if(dinero > 200) {

                        labelTexto.setText("Monto incorrecto!");


                    }



                    if(dinero <= 200){

                        labelTexto.setText("Dinero retirado: " + dinero + " euros");

                        balance = balance-dinero;

                        labelBalance.setText("Balance: " + balance + " euros");



                    }

                    if(balance <= 0)  {

                        //System.exit(0);

                        balance = 0;

                        labelBalance.setText("Balance: " + balance + " euros");

                        labelTexto.setText("FUERA DE SERVICIO!");

                    }




                }

                else if(cuenta.equals("Corriente")) {

                    if(dinero > 400) {

                        labelTexto.setText("Monto incorrecto!");


                    }


                    if(dinero <= 400){

                        labelTexto.setText("Dinero retirado: " + dinero + " euros");

                        balance = balance-dinero;

                        labelBalance.setText("Balance: " + balance + " euros");



                    }

                    if(balance <= 0)  {

                        //System.exit(0);

                        balance = 0;

                        labelBalance.setText("Balance: " + balance + " euros");

                        labelTexto.setText("FUERA DE SERVICIO!");

                    }





                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ! Podrias copiarme el codigo aquí ? ya que no me permite abrirlo

Comment: Debes dejar el codigo fuente y la explicación en esta misma respuesta.